# Why is the UITableViewController numberOfRowsInSections called before the init method?

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform

My UITableViewController won't load the information that I have downloaded from Parse. I know that the link is working because when I ask it to print out the PFQuery, I get the results I want. However, my problem is that the method numberOfRowsInSection is called before the init method. I'm not really sure how to download my data before the init method.

Here is my .m file

```
@implementation PicklerTable

@synthesize picklersArray;

- (id) init
{
     // Call the cuperclass's designated init
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

if(self){

    // Insert initial data here
    PFQuery *picklerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Picklers"];

    [picklerQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            picklersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];                
        }
    }];

}

return self;
}


-(id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
return [self init];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return picklersArray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

PFObject *picklerObject = [picklersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];    
[[cell textLabel] setText:[picklerObject objectForKey:@"title"]];

return cell;
}
```

I put a breakpoint in the numberOfRowsInSection method and typed bt into the console. This was my output:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x00003430 TableControllerPractice`-[PicklerTable tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:](self=0x07c7d5a0, _cmd=0x01426163, tableView=0x08398a00, section=0) + 64 at PicklerTable.m:50, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
frame #0: 0x00003430 TableControllerPractice`-[PicklerTable tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:](self=0x07c7d5a0, _cmd=0x01426163, tableView=0x08398a00, section=0) + 64 at PicklerTable.m:50
frame #1: 0x01074548 UIKit`-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 1822
frame #2: 0x01077224 UIKit`-[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 98
frame #3: 0x00f3b952 UIKit`-[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 120
frame #4: 0x00f3b2dc UIKit`-[UITableView reloadData] + 769
frame #5: 0x00f3edd6 UIKit`-[UITableView _reloadDataIfNeeded] + 65
frame #6: 0x00f43a7e UIKit`-[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 36
frame #7: 0x00ee02dd UIKit`-[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 279
frame #8: 0x01d366b0 libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
frame #9: 0x00424fc0 QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 240
frame #10: 0x0041933c QuartzCore`CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 468
frame #11: 0x00424eaf QuartzCore`-[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 166
frame #12: 0x00f7f2bd UIKit`-[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 242
frame #13: 0x00ec7b56 UIKit`-[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 5346
frame #14: 0x00ec666f UIKit`-[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 82
frame #15: 0x00ec6589 UIKit`-[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 89
frame #16: 0x00ec57e4 UIKit`__57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke_0 + 224
frame #17: 0x00ec561e UIKit`-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 209
frame #18: 0x00ec63d9 UIKit`-[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 853
frame #19: 0x00ec92d2 UIKit`-[UIWindow setDelegate:] + 351
frame #20: 0x00f7399c UIKit`-[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 164
frame #21: 0x00ec0574 UIKit`-[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 481
frame #22: 0x00ec076f UIKit`-[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 368
frame #23: 0x00ec0905 UIKit`-[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
frame #24: 0x00ec9917 UIKit`-[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 65
frame #25: 0x00002da6 TableControllerPractice`-[HomepwnerAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](self=0x07c62cb0, _cmd=0x01426c21, application=0x0b05cb60, launchOptions=0x00000000) + 742 at HomepwnerAppDelegate.m:33
frame #26: 0x00e8d157 UIKit`-[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 266
frame #27: 0x00e8d747 UIKit`-[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1248
frame #28: 0x00e8e94b UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 805
frame #29: 0x00e9fcb5 UIKit`-[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1022
frame #30: 0x00ea0beb UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
frame #31: 0x00e92698 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEvent + 9874
frame #32: 0x0292bdf9 GraphicsServices`_PurpleEventCallback + 339
frame #33: 0x0292bad0 GraphicsServices`PurpleEventCallback + 46
frame #34: 0x01e72bf5 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
frame #35: 0x01e72962 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
frame #36: 0x01ea3bb6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2118
frame #37: 0x01ea2f44 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
frame #38: 0x01ea2e1b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #39: 0x00e8e17a UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 774
frame #40: 0x00e8fffc UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1211
frame #41: 0x00002a8d TableControllerPractice`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffff2d4) + 141 at main.m:16
frame #42: 0x000029b5 TableControllerPractice`start + 53
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.  When it's hit, type `bt` in the debugger console.  Copy the output and paste it into your question.

Comment: Just did though what exactly does bt do?

Comment: The `bt` command stands for “back trace”.  It prints the call stack.  Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: No I am not using a storyboards and everything works if I explicitly set the cells titles with a pre-created fake array. I really think that the issue is simply the fact that I am unable to create the array from Parse before the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection method is called.

Comment: Is your `PicklerTable` its own delegate?  Based on the code you posted, it appears to be.

Comment: PicklerTable is a subclass of UITableViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this in your `init` method:

```
[picklerQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        picklersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];                
    }
}];
```

So it's going to kick off the query on a background thread and continue execution on the main thread before it receives the results of the query.

Later, when the query results arrive, it will run your block (on the main thread, I presume), at which time the block sets the `picklersArray` instance variable.

At that point, you need to tell the table view to reload its data.  Try this:

```
[picklerQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        picklersArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```